# SignalR ASP.Net 4.6: Some time client not received message from Server when I call http request

Tags: asp.net, signalr

Some time client not received message from Server when I call http request. When I deploy on IIS physic server, it working fine but when I deploy on App Service Azure sometime client not received message from Server . When I call from Chorme, client not received but I call for FireFox client received message normal.

Comment: There is a known issue with Chrome fixed in SignalR version 2.4.2.  Which version are you using?